# Subtracting current date from future date reutrns negative

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hey I'm extremely puzzled as to why the value I'm displaying is negative. I am selecting a date in the future, so shouldn't it have a larger millisecond value then the current time?

```
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
            Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

            try {
                c1.setTime(sdf.parse(res.getString(1)));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


           c2.getTime();
            displayMsg.setText((c1.getTimeInMillis()-c2.getTimeInMillis())/(1000*60)+ " minutes");
```

Comment: Pretty sure `DD` is off in your format. Because that is "day in year". You want `dd`.

Comment: How do we know the date is in the future? Did you try printing it? Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

if you look at the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you will see that `DD` means "day in year" rather than `dd`, which is "day in month". So make it:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, i am still learning java and these quick concise replies help alot

Answer (score 0):

try not to go in such disputes because it's never better to write such hectic code.

Use Pretty Time Library on Github... 
[Pretty Time Library](https://github.com/ocpsoft/prettytime)

I think you not need any help more than that.

Rather than that your question is not complete. As well as try using yyyy-MM-dd.